# Does this double product equal an exponential function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

I was looking at the graph of $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(\Gamma(n+1)\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(n+x+1\right)\Gamma\left(n-x+1\right)}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\left(n+k\right)^2}\right)$$

I noticed that it looks much like a normal curve of height $1$.

So is this equal to the form $e^{\frac{-x^2}{v}}$ for some $v$?

Or essentially the same question: does
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ln\left(1-\frac{x}{\left(n+k\right)^2}\right)=-\frac{x}{v}$$
for some $v$?

**Edit** [Related Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3186236/193034) on the partial product.

Comment: Is the upper limit of $k$ correct?

Comment: Yes. I'm using the known result, $\frac{\left(\Gamma(n+1)\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(n+xi+1\right)\Gamma\left(n-xi+1\right)}=\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{x^2}{\left(n+k\right)^2}\right)$

Comment: Major update ! Have a look at my last edit. Cheers :-)

Comment: It is possible to justify $(1)$ and $(2)$ from $(3)$. If you are concerned, I could elaborate.

Comment: Please, yes. I would be most interest. @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: @tyobrien; Work done ! In fact, I have been able to write$$\log(f_p(x))=\sum_{n=1}^{m} a_n x^{2n}$$ with explicit expressions for the $a_n$'s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A problem is that
the sum diverges.

$\begin{array}\\
s(x)
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\ln\left(1-\frac{x}{\left(n+k\right)^2}\right)\\
&\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{x}{(n+k)^{2}}
\quad\text{since }-\ln(1-z) \ge z \text{ if } z \ge 0\\
&=x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^{2}}\\
&\ge x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k(k+1)}\\
&= x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty (\dfrac1{k}-\dfrac1{k+1})\\
&= x\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac1{n+1}\\
\end{array}
$

and this diverges.

Answer (score 5):

The observation is interesting *per se*.

In fact, if we consider
$$f_p(x)=\prod_{n=1}^p\frac{\left(\Gamma(n+1)\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(n+x+1\right)\,\Gamma\left(n-x+1\right)}$$ we can find (using a CAS) that
$$f_p(x)=\frac{ G(p+2)^2 \, G(2-x)\, G(2+x) }{G(p+2-x)\, G(p+2+x)}\left(-\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x(x^2-1)}\frac{G(3-x)\, G(3+x) }{ G(2-x)\, G(2+x)}\right)^p$$ where appear  the [Barnes G-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_G-function).

For the simplest $p=1$, 
$$f_1(x)=-\frac{\sin (\pi  x)}{\pi x  \left(x^2-1\right)}$$ does not show such a shape but, increasing $p$ more and more, we can effectively notice what you observed.

The problem, as @marty cohen answered, is that there is no limit to this function.

What is numerically interesting is the computation of $x$ such that $f_p(x)=\frac 12$. Here are some results ( the table has been updated after the edit).
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}\
p & \text{exact} & \text{using } (1) &\text{using } (2) &\text{using } (3)\\
 10   &  0.543223 & 0.486469 & 0.567259 & 0.545324 \\
 20   &  0.481383 & 0.438933 & 0.497577 & 0.482529 \\
 30   &  0.452924 & 0.416538 & 0.466221 & 0.453767 \\
 40   &  0.435333 & 0.402499 & 0.447040 & 0.436024 \\
 50   &  0.422935 & 0.392505 & 0.433608 & 0.423532 \\
 60   &  0.413516 & 0.384854 & 0.423448 & 0.414049 \\
 70   &  0.406002 & 0.378714 & 0.415372 & 0.406488 \\
 80   &  0.399801 & 0.373622 & 0.408723 & 0.400251 \\
 90   &  0.394552 & 0.369293 & 0.403108 & 0.394973 \\
 100  &  0.390022 & 0.365543 & 0.398270 & 0.390419 \\
 200  &  0.363578 & 0.343397 & 0.370187 & 0.363856 \\
 300  &  0.350356 & 0.332155 & 0.356240 & 0.350588 \\
 400  &  0.341793 & 0.324812 & 0.347238 & 0.341998 \\
 500  &  0.335563 & 0.319439 & 0.340703 & 0.335749 \\
 600  &  0.330715 & 0.315240 & 0.335627 & 0.330888 \\
 700  &  0.326775 & 0.311816 & 0.331507 & 0.326938 \\
 800  &  0.323472 & 0.308938 & 0.328057 & 0.323627 \\
 900  &  0.320640 & 0.306464 & 0.325101 & 0.320788 \\
 1000 &  0.318169 & 0.304301 & 0.322524 & 0.318311
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Taking logarithms of the product and using Stirling approximation, a very crude approximation would be 
$$\color{blue}{f_p(x) \sim \exp\left({-x^2 H_p}\right)}\tag 1$$
A better one would be
$$\color{blue}{f_p(x) \sim \exp\left({-x^2 \left(H_p-\frac{1}{2}H_p^{(2)}\right)}\right)}\tag 2$$
Just computing the second derivative at $x=0$ would give as a much much better approximation (this is the exact second order Taylor expansion of $f_p(x)$ buil at $x=0$)
$$\color{red}{f_p(x) \sim \exp\left(-x^2 \left(\psi ^{(0)}(p+2)+(p+1)\, \psi ^{(1)}(p+2)+\gamma-\frac{\pi ^2}{6} \right)\right)}\tag 3$$

Considering the asymptotics of the constant $k_{i,p}$ which appears in equation $(i)$, we can see that they are very closely related to each other
$$k_{1,p}=\log(p)+\gamma +\frac{1}{2 p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$

$$k_{2,p}= \log(p)+\left(\gamma-\frac{\pi ^2}{12}\right)   +\frac{1}{p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right) $$

$$k_{3,p}=\log(p)+\left(\gamma-\frac{\pi ^2}{6}   +1\right)+\frac{1}{p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right) $$

Moreover, computing, we can notice that $k_{3,p}\approx k_{1,p}-\frac 23$.

The advantage of these appromations is that, if we need to solve for $x$, $f_p(x)=a$, we have a very good estimate to start Newton method. For illustration, considering $p=100$ and $a=\frac 14$, we would get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.55213548373373596669 \\
 1 & 0.55099521268758128733 \\
 2 & 0.55099729839656297058 \\
 3 & 0.55099729840353755347
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for twenty significant figures.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was interested to see.

Comment: @tyobrien. You are welcome ! I had fun with the problem. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 3):

*I prefer to add another answer for an extension of the work.*

Considering
$$f_p(x)=\prod_{n=1}^p\frac{\left(\Gamma(n+1)\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(n+x+1\right)\,\Gamma\left(n-x+1\right)}$$

$$\log\left(f_p(x) \right)=\sum_{n=1}^p \log\left(\frac{\left(\Gamma(n+1)\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(n+x+1\right)\,\Gamma\left(n-x+1\right)} \right)$$

Using Taylor expansion
$$\log\left(\frac{\left(\Gamma(n+1)\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(n+x+1\right)\,\Gamma\left(n-x+1\right)}\right)=-2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\psi ^{(2 k-1)}(n+1)}{(2 k)!}x^{2k}$$ and what remain is to compute the sums over $n$.

Writing
$$\log\left(f_p(x) \right)=c_1 x^2+c_2 x^4+c_3 x^6 + c_4 x^8+\cdots$$  that is to say
$$f_p(x)=\exp(c_1 x^2+c_2 x^4+c_3 x^6 + c_4 x^8+\cdots)$$
we should have
$$c_1=-\psi ^{(0)}(p+2)-(p+1) \psi ^{(1)}(p+2)-\gamma+\frac{\pi^2}6$$
$$c_2=\frac{-45 \psi ^{(2)}(p+2)-15 (p+1) \psi ^{(3)}(p+2)-90 \zeta
   (3)+\pi ^4}{180} $$
$$c_3=\frac{-315 \psi ^{(4)}(p+2)-63 (p+1) \psi ^{(5)}(p+2)+8 \left(\pi ^6-945 \zeta
   (5)\right)}{22680}$$
$$c_4=\frac{-105 \psi ^{(6)}(p+2)-15 (p+1) \psi ^{(7)}(p+2)+8 \left(\pi ^8-9450 \zeta
   (7)\right)}{302400}$$
For any value of $p$, all coefficients are negative and they are smaller and smaller; this justifies the approximation given by $(3)$ in the previous answer.

For infinitely large values of $p$, we have
$$\frac {c_2}{c_1} \sim \frac{90 \zeta (3)-\pi^4}{30 \left(6 \log (p)-\pi ^2+6 \gamma +6\right)}$$
$$\frac {c_3}{c_2} \sim \frac{4 \left(\pi ^6-945 \zeta (5)\right)}{63 \left(\pi ^4-90 \zeta (3)\right)}\approx 0.109046$$
$$\frac {c_4}{c_3} \sim \frac{3 \left(\pi ^8-9450 \zeta (7)\right)}{40 \left(\pi ^6-945 \zeta (5)\right)}\approx 0.163594$$

**Warning**

Better material in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186236/a-partial-product-involving-the-gamma-function/3187428?noredirect=1#comment6561072_3187428).