# A Partial product involving the Gamma function

Tags: sequences-and-series

I previously asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3183215/193034) about the shape of the following infinite product involving the Gamma function.

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left(\Gamma(n+1)\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(n+x+1\right)\Gamma\left(n-x+1\right)}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\left(n+k\right)^2}\right)$$

It appeared to fit a normal curve very well for more terms, which made me wonder if it had the form of an exponential.  The problem, as you can see from @marty cohen’s answer, is that the product diverges.

But what about the partial product?

$$\prod_{n=1}^m\frac{\left(\Gamma(n+1)\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(n+x+1\right)\Gamma\left(n-x+1\right)}$$

Can we find an exact or asymptotic formula to shed some light on the shape of this function?

Comment: Did you look at my last edit to your previous question ? This is exactly what I worked and wrote in my second answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Revised version after @tyobrien key remark.*

As I wrote in my first answer to your previous question, there is a closed form expressionfor$$f_p(x)=\prod_{n=1}^p\frac{\left(\Gamma(n+1)\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(n+x+1\right)\,\Gamma\left(n-x+1\right)}$$
It is given in terms of  the Barnes G-function (sometimes named  the double gamma function) and write
$$f_p(x)=\frac{ G(p+2)^2 \, G(2-x)\, G(2+x) }{G(p+2-x)\, G(p+2+x)}$$

This $G(.)$ is pretty documented (google for it) and seems to be related to many other functions (have a look [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.17)).

Concerning the asymptotics, as I wrote in my second answer to your previous question, it seems that, building the Taylor expansion around $x=0$, we have very good approximations looking like
$$f_p(x)=\exp\left(-\sum_{i=1}^\infty c_k^{(p)} x^{2k} \right)$$ where all coefficients have an explicit formulation in terms of polygamma and zeta functions (all of them are positive). To make them clearer and to see some possible patters, writing
$$c_k^{(p)}=d_k^{(p)}+e_k^{(p)}$$ the first are given in the table below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & d_k^{(p)} & e_k^{(p)} \\
 1 & \psi ^{(0)}(p+2)+(p+1) \psi ^{(1)}(p+2) & -\frac{\pi ^2}{6}+\gamma \\
 2 & \frac{3 \psi ^{(2)}(p+2)+(p+1) \psi ^{(3)}(p+2)}{12}  & -\frac{\pi
   ^4}{180}+\frac{\zeta (3)}{2} \\
 3 & \frac{5 \psi ^{(4)}(p+2)+(p+1) \psi ^{(5)}(p+2)}{360}  & -\frac{\pi
   ^6}{2835}+\frac{\zeta (5)}{3} \\
 4 & \frac{7 \psi ^{(6)}(p+2)+(p+1) \psi ^{(7)}(p+2)}{20160} & -\frac{\pi
   ^8}{37800}+\frac{\zeta (7)}{4} \\
 5 & \frac{297 \psi ^{(8)}(p+2)+33 (p+1) \psi ^{(9)}(p+2)}{59875200} & -\frac{\pi
   ^{10}}{467775}+\frac{\zeta (9)}{5} \\
 6 & \frac{11 \psi ^{(10)}(p+2)+(p+1) \psi ^{(11)}(p+2)}{239500800} & -\frac{691 \pi^{12}}{3831077250}+\frac{\zeta (11)}{6}\\
 7 & \frac{39 \psi ^{(12)}(p+2)+3 (p+1) \psi ^{(13)}(p+2)}{130767436800} &-\frac{2 \pi ^{14}}{127702575}+\frac{\zeta (13)}{7}
\end{array}
\right)$$

This does confirm your interesting observation.

By the way, you could be interested by [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=2ahUKEwipjYO00c_hAhXj8eAKHSZtBNgQFjAFegQICBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2Fmath%2F0308086&usg=AOvVaw21W1jNxuNq5VmyOXArSRdU).

**Numerical aspects**

As said earlier, the first term is, from far away, the most significant. In order to check, I computed
$$\Phi(a)=\int_{-3}^3 \left(f_{100}(x)-e^{-a x^2}\right)^2\,dx$$ which I minimized with respect to $a$. The optimum is found for $a=4.5645$ to be compared with 
$c_1^{(100)}=4.5474$.

Comment: Well done. I am definitely going to continue studying this function.

Comment: @tyobrien. Would you accept the answer ? Being serious, I think that a lot could be done with this problem, even a thesis may be. To tell the truth, I cannot stop working on it ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Big clean up: Notice that $\Gamma(2-x)\Gamma(2+x)=-\frac{\pi x(x^2-1)}{\sin(\pi x)}$. So we totally eliminate that power term.

Comment: @tyobrien. Big point ! I shall update and add more stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Your list presents some clear patterns.  The denominators in $d_k^{(p)}$ when fully reduced are surely $(2k)!/2$ see https://oeis.org/A002674.  And it's suggested that $e_k^{(p)}=\frac{-\zeta(2k)+\zeta(2k-1)}{k}$.

Comment: @tyobrien. So good ! When I wrote that this was an interesting problem ! I started this morning at 3:00am. Let us continue and add more stuff. Cheers.

Comment: I added some details about the coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

*This is an extension of the work by @Claude Leibovici.*

Here we derive the explicit formula for the coefficients in the power series equal to the product.

Begin with the Taylor expansion:

$$\log\left(\frac{\left(\Gamma(n+1)\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(n+x+1\right)\,\Gamma\left(n-x+1\right)}\right)=-2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\psi ^{(2 k-1)}(n+1)}{(2 k)!}x^{2k}$$

The goal then is to evaluate
$$\sum_{n=1}^p\psi^{(2k-1)}(n+1).$$

Using the recurrence relation
$$\psi^{(m)}(x+1)=\psi^{(m)}(x)+\frac{(-1)^m m!}{x^{m+1}}$$

we can derive

$$\sum_{n=1}^p\psi^{(2k-1)}(n+1)=p\psi^{(2k-1)}(p+2)+(2k-1)!\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{i}{(i+1)^{2k}}.$$

The final sum is

\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{i}{(i+1)^{2k}}
&=\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{1}{(i+1)^{2k-1}}-\sum_{i=1}^p\frac{1}{(i+1)^{2k}}
\\&=\zeta(2k-1)-1-\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(i+p+2)^{2k-1}}
\\&\space\space\space\space\space-\left[\zeta(2k)-1-\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(i+p+2)^{2k}}\right]
\\&=\zeta(2k-1)-\zeta(2k)+\frac{\psi^{(2k-2)}(p+2)}{(2k-2)!}+\frac{\psi^{(2k-1)}(p+2)}{(2k-1)!}.
\end{align}

Therefore
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^p\psi^{(2k-1)}(n+1)&=p\psi^{(2k-1)}(p+2)+(2k-1)!(\zeta(2k-1)-\zeta(2k))+(2k-1)\psi^{(2k-2)}(p+2)+\psi^{(2k-1)}(p+2)
\\&=(2k-1)\psi^{(2k-2)}(p+2)+(p+1)\psi^{(2k-1)}(p+2)+(2k-1)!(\zeta(2k-1)-\zeta(2k)).
\end{align}

So now we have $$\sum_{n=1}^p\log\left(\frac{\left(\Gamma(n+1)\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(n+x+1\right)\,\Gamma\left(n-x+1\right)}\right)=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k^{(p)} x^{2k}$$

where
$$c_k^{(p)}=\frac{2(2k-1)\psi^{(2k-2)}(p+2)+2(p+1)\psi^{(2k-1)}(p+2)}{(2k)!}+\frac{\zeta(2k-1)-\zeta(2k)}{k}.$$

Note that by using the definition of $\psi^{(m)}(z)$ for positive $m$, the divergent effects of $\psi^{(0)}(z)$ and $\zeta(1)$ cancel each other out.

Update:  We can easily simplify this to
$$c_k^{(p)}=\frac{p\zeta(2k)+H_{p+1,2k-1}-(p+1)H_{p+1,2k}}{k}$$

Summing over these gives us

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k^{(p)} x^{2k} 
&= p\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\zeta(2k)}{k}x^{2k}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_{p+1,2k-1}}{k}x^{2k}-(p+1)\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_{p+1,2k}}{k}x^{2k}
\\&=p\log\left(\frac{\pi x}{\sin(\pi x)}\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{p+1}n\log\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^2\right)+(p+1)\sum_{n=1}^{p+1}\log\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^2\right)
\\&=p\log\left(\frac{\pi x}{\sin(\pi x)}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^{p+1}(p+1-n)\log\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^2\right)
\end{align}

Which finally gives us the very nice result
$$\prod_{n=1}^p\frac{\left(\Gamma(n+1)\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(n+x+1\right)\,\Gamma\left(n-x+1\right)}=\left(\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}\right)^p\,\,\prod_{n=1}^{p+1}\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^2\right)^{n-p-1}$$

Or just for completeness, starting at $n=0$,
\begin{align}
\prod_{n=0}^p\frac{\left(\Gamma(n+1)\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(n+x+1\right)\,\Gamma\left(n-x+1\right)}
&=\left(\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}\right)^{p+1}\,\,\prod_{n=1}^{p+1}\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^2\right)^{n-p-1}
\\
&=\left(\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x \prod_{n=1}^{p+1}\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^2\right)}\right)^{p+1}\,\,\prod_{n=1}^{p+1}\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^2\right)^n
\\
&=\left(\frac{\Gamma(p+2)^2}{\Gamma(p+x+2)\,\Gamma(p-x+2)}\right)^{p+1}\,\,\prod_{n=1}^{p+1}\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^2\right)^n
\\
&=\left(\frac{\Gamma(p+1)^2}{\Gamma(p+x+1)\,\Gamma(p-x+1)}\right)^{p+1}\,\,\prod_{n=1}^{p}\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^2\right)^n
\end{align}

Notice that numerically the first term appears to tend to $e^{-x^2}$
$$\left(\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x \prod_{n=1}^{p+1}\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^2\right)}\right)^{p+1}\to e^{-x^2}$$
But I'm not sure how to prove it at the moment.

Thus the divergence is all in the product $\prod_{n=1}^{p+1}\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^2\right)^n$.

Comment: Good work ! $\to +1$ for sure. Cheers :-)

Comment: I would like to discuss about this work. If you wish, you can contact me by e-mail (my address is in my profile) or open a chat room here and ask me to join it. Cheers.

Comment: Sounds good https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92507/interesting-product-discussion

Answer (score 1):

*This is too long for a comment.*

Let us consider
$$a_p=\left(\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{(\pi x) \prod_{n=1}^{p+1}\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^2\right)}\right)^{p+1}$$
$$\prod_{n=1}^{p+1}\left(1-\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^2\right)=\frac{(1-x)_{p+1} (x+1)_{p+1}}{((p+1)!)^2}$$
$$\log(a_p)=(p+1) \log \left(\frac{((p+1)!)^2 \sin (\pi  x)}{(\pi  x) (1-x)_{p+1} (x+1)_{p+1}}\right)$$ Now, expand as Taylor series around $x=0$ to get
$$\log(a_p)=-(p+1) \psi ^{(1)}(p+2)x^2+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Now, using asymtotics
$$-(p+1) \psi ^{(1)}(p+2)=-1+\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{2}{3 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

Comment: This is good. I noticed $a_p$ can be written in another form. See my updated answer.